# Security considerations for a default install?

Tags: installation, security, default

So with an old burned install CD of Feisty Fawn I went through the process of completely formatting the Windows OS and installing Ubuntu on an old XP laptop. I then went through the online upgrade to 10.4 LTS, only installing the gnome desktop environment package in the process.

My (admittedly very open) question is that in this state and online, what security considerations do I have to immediately make for the default install? I understand that a lot of this swings on my intended use of the server, but just sitting there online what risks is it exposed to (this obviously goes far beyond the realm of linux, but I am not sure how these risks are accommodated in the default install). For example, I believe there is a firewall installed with Ubuntu but by default it allows all traffic.

Any other guidelines would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Community Documentation's security chapter](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Security) is a good starting point. For a server you should read [the security chapter in the server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/security.html), too

Answer (score 1):

You should feel secure, at least for the time being, because there are no services running by default. In addition, if you have a router between your ISP router and your computer, then your network is probably using private addressing, anyway, like 192.168.something. (And that router would need a specific instruction to forward certain packets from your public address to your private address.) There's plenty of time for Florian's first comment.

Answer (score 0):

As you say it does depend on exactly what you will use this for, but usual practice is:

- Understand what services you want?
  HTTP? SSL? SMTP? Ensure all others
  are disabled/removed
- Use some form of filtering to allow
  only those services, and you reduce
  the potential threat footprint (in
  case malicious or accidental services
  exist on the server)

Depending on your threat, you may want to run the initial install behind a firewall which only allows outbound connections. This is what I would recommend for any install which may need to download updates - it helps to remove the threat of compromise before updates and patches are implemented.

Answer (score -1):

None.

There is no firewall needed for a default Ubuntu system because there are no insecure services listening by default.

Comment: In the default installation Ubuntu doesn't have any services listening to external traffic.